# Best practice for handling down casts due to C++ C2664 when compiling 64 bit

Tags: c++, pointers, 64-bit, c2664

I have an exposed method that accepts a long* as a parameter  like this:

```
void  MyClass::MyPublicMethod(long *pLong)
```

Inside this method, I call a system API that accepts an INT64*, like this:

```
void  MyClass::MyPublicMethod(long *pLong) 
{
    //SomeAPI::APIMethod(INT64* p64);
    SomeAPI::APIMethod(&pLong);
}
```

When compiling as x64, I get an error (rightly so):

```
error C2664: 'SomeAPI::APIMethod(int64* p64)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'long*' to 'INT64*'
```

I do not want to change my exposed method's signature because it will have many downstream consequences. What is the best way to address this situation, assuming that I know that p64 will not exceed the limits of a long?

Something like this?

```
void  MyClass::MyPublicMethod(long *pLong) 
{
    // Use a local INT64 for the API call.
    INT64 tmp64 = *pLong;
    //SomeAPI::APIMethod(INT64* p64);
    SomeAPI::APIMethod(&tmp64);
    *pLong = (long)tmp64;
}
```

Comment: It's not exactly beautiful, but that certainly seems like the most straightforward way to handle it.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are seeing is a manifestation of the fact the `sizeof(long)` on the platform you are testing, which I presume is Windows, is 32 bit (as opposed to 64). You can try testing that premise.

If that is true, you may want to pass in `long long` which should be 64 bit. You will then have to change the method signature.

As a side note, when you write this,

```
    *pLong = (long)tmp64;
```

You are typecasting a 64-bit value to 32-bit's. Is there a guarantee that the `APIMethod` is always returning a 32-bit value. If not, that's a problem.